# Unusual Separators 'space + tab'

Tags: r

I have a table of info from the web with unusual separators.  Between columns, it has '1-space and '1-tab'.  When I used the std. 'read.table' with sep=" \t" R kicked it back saying it could only take one byte for a separation.  Can I use 'read.table' or something else or should I just run gsub or grep, instead?

Comment: Doesn't the default, `sep=""`, split on white space?

Comment: @joran is correct; you shouldn't need to specify `sep=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this parameter to your *read.table* call keeping `sep='\t'`:

```
strip.white=TRUE
```

Setting this flag to `TRUE` will strip leading and trailing white space (unless quoted) that surrounds each entry in a column.

Comment: yep--since i'm nearly always working on python and R projects side-by-side, i do that all the time (as well as 'len' instead of 'length'). Edited to fix.